# ubuntu 10.04 lamp installation

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I have tried to install a lamp sever on my ubuntu 10.04 (home) installation by typing this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

However, afterwards, when I point my browser towards http://localhost I geta 403 Forbidden error. I tried multiple times to change the permissions of the /var/www/ folder by right clicking it and setting the permissions to read and write for my user, but it just goes back to what it was after I close the options window.

HELP

Comment: What do you expect instead of the error 403 when loading `http://localhost/`? Have you placed any files into the directory `/var/www/`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [chapter about Apache httpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html) in the Ubuntu Server Guide. It describes the setup fairly well and should answer your questions.

The error 403 when browsing `http://localhost/` suggests that there is no `index.html` in `/var/www` and that `Options +Indexes` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

[LAMP Setup](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-10.04-lamp) try above link its work

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use tasksel instead for the package.

`sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

Then check if your apache is running with the following:

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status`

More docs to read here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html

Comment: `apt-get install lamp-server^` is the same as `tasksel install lamp-server`. Just look at the output of `tasksel -t install lamp-server`.

Comment: Those were the instructions from the Ubuntu Community help page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP